# Titillium Web Font applied to Select element

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, html-select

I have to use Titillium Web font for a Select element inside a web-page, and I have also to use specific font-size and font-weight values.
the problem is, with the specified values, the text inside the select element is shifted down and the lower edges are hidden! 
I've tried using the following css properties on the select element:

```
vertical-align: text-top !important;
line-height: 80%;
```

but none works! Can any one help me solve this please?